# Why this simple class method is not working

Tags: smalltalk

I am trying to understand smalltalk and trying following simple code with gnu-smalltalk:

```
Object subclass: Myclass[
    myMethod: val [val printNl]
]

mc := Myclass new.
mc myMethod: "55".
```

However, it does not work and gives following error:

```
$gst simpleclass.st 
simpleclass.st:6: expected object
```

I thought `"55"` is an object in smalltalk.

Obviously I am missing something very basic but I am not able to figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why

```
mc := Myclass new.
mc myMethod: "55".
```

doesn't work is simple: In Smalltalk double quoted strings are comments. Hence, for the compiler, your expression is equivalent to:

```
mc myMethod:
```

as if there was no argument whatsoever. The intended expression should have been

```
mc myMethod: 55 "and now this should work!"
```

Comment: Don't! Nobody is born knowing Smalltalk!